# Testing objects created inside the class

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a method like this:

```
public void ABC(ViewModeL model)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(int));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(int));                     
        var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
        dr["column1"] = 2;
        dr["column2"] = 0;
     }
```

I want to assert on the dataTable object but I am not able to figure out how to do so, since it is created inside the method and also it is not returned by this method. Is it possible to test it using rhino mocks??

Comment: Why you want to assert DataTable if it has no connections with outward things?

Comment: Because I am adding stuff in it, and i want to know whether they are added in the right manner.

Comment: This is not the point of unit testing. Unit tests test **what** the function/object does, not **how** they do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a local variable which life-space is `ABC()` method scope. So thsi is not possible from `C#` perspectives and even wrong from unit test perspectives such you must not relie on the implementation details.

Perhaps you've provided not entire method body since `dataTable` variable will die after `ABC()` method execution, so why you need checking it?

Comment: I am calling another method in which i am passing the dataTable object from inside my method.      repository.InsertDataTable(dataTable);

Comment: Hey I refactored my code and created a protected method which will return the DataTable object and tested it indepedently by generating partial mock. Thanks anyway.. :-)